# Display LOV return value in Link

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Apex 23.1.3.
and I have an interactive report with a **Link Column** and I want to have one of columns which has LOV on it , in my link.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4OWw.png)
And I see the display value of LOV in URl ! I want to have return value in target URl.

> target URL example :
>
> ?**p9_dept=**ACCOUNTING****&session=104401221993176 ....

> **p9_dept has to show the ID ( return value ) of LOV in link not the name (display value ) !**

How can I have have return value in url ?

Comment: Can you update your question with  a reproducible example on the emp/dept sample schema to allow us to see exactly how you're doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

In interactive Report, only display values of the LOV are presented in the HTML DOM after page initialization, so you may have to write the URl manually during report initiization.
The following snippet of sql code used as region resource of the report.

```
select EMPNO,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO,
       PHONE_NUMBER,
       JOB_ID,
       ENAME,
       '<a href="'||
        APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL (
            p_url => 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':5:'||:APP_SESSION||'::NO:RP,5:P5_DEPTNO:'||DEPTNO,
            p_checksum_type => 'SESSION')
      ||'"><span>'||DEPTNO||'</span></a>' AS dept_link
  from EMP
```

see [APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/PREPARE_URL-Function.html) for details about the function.